Why does my .then execute before the prior one is finished?
The following page fetches an array of database rows from a php page, then instantiates each row as an object.
After the rows have been instantiated and added to an array, I want to build my html table from the array of objects using the buildTable function.
However, the buildTable function executes prior to the array of objects being populated even though it is in .then.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,


var lotID;
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  getQCDims(12346);
})
var QCDims = [];
class QCDim {
  ID;
  Bal;
  Name;
  constructor(row) {
    this.ID = row.QCDimID;
    this.Bal = row.QCDimBalloon;
    this.Name = row.QCDimDisplayName;
    console.log("Bal" + row.QCDimBalloon);
  }
}

function getQCDims(lotID) {
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("operation", "getQCDim");
  params.append("lotID", lotID);

  fetch("datarequests_QCDisplay.php", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "no-cache",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      redirect: "follow",
      referrer: "no-referrer",
      body: params,
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.status > 0) throw data.reason;
      return data.rows;
    })
    .then(rows => {
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
        QCDims.push(new QCDim(rows[i]))
      }
    })
    .then(buildTable())
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
}

function buildTable() {
  console.log("Build Table");
  console.log("QCDims.length=" + QCDims.length);
  let newHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < QCDims.length - 1; i++) {
    newHTML = newHTML + "<th>" + QCDims[i].Bal + "</th>";
  }
  $("#mythead").html(newHTML);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead id="mythead"></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>




.then(buildTable()) should be .then(buildTable) (then takes a callback function as a parameter, not the result of calling that function)
